# Why YouTube videos buffers slowly in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, video, youtube

I watch YouTube videos on Internet Explorer when i had Windows 7 couple months before upgrading my PC to Windows 10 because it buffers videos faster than other browsers but as i upgraded to Windows 10 everything had changed -- buffering slowly. Why is it? Windows 10 eats my data package faster while watching Youtube.

When I had windows 7 i can watch videos without exhausting much data. **When i watch 30 min or 1 hr video the whole video buffers quickly then i disconnect my USB modem this way it saves much data but now when i disconnect modem video also gets disconnected. With Windows 7 system even if i disconnects while the buffet gets middle of the video or at any point the video continues streaming up to that point but windows 10 doesn't work like that. Why is it?**

I am having 4GB data allowance for USD 20--i am located near south most tip of India.

**EDIT:** I watch videos at 360 or 480p. Watching videos on Chrome sucks my data package even more--i have experienced it. I watched videos by disabling Flash in Windows 7--when flash is on i cannot watch videos the way i mentioned (on Internet Explorer). **My point is how can i watch the video up to the buffered point even if i disconnects internet connection.**

Answer (score 1):

You are watching movies in higher quality which means more data transmitted.

You can either manually change the quality for each video using the cog in the lower right corner of the video or try a browser plug-in like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/your-quality-for-youtube/nfcilgimggemnogfigihdkmapdhhlbph (which requires the Chrome Browser)

The better higher the number the better the video quality and thus more data transfered

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

1) A different browser.

2) Reinstall Adobe Flash Player.

3) Run a network test.

4) Lower Quality (Don't use HD or even 720p)

5) Try booting live from Linux and see if the issue persists.